# NotImplementedError: Cannot convert a symbolic Tensor (cond_2/strided_slice:0)

Tags: tensorflow, object, object-detection-api

I have an issue with tensorflow object detection API's, when training the sdd_model_mobnet i get the below error:
***" NotImplementedError: Cannot convert a symbolic Tensor (cond_2/strided_slice:0) to a numpy array. This error may indicate that you're trying to pass a Tensor to a NumPy call, which is not supported"***

environment specification (windows Enterprise 10):

1. windows Enterprise 10
2. Anaconda
3. python 3.8.8
4. numpy 1.20.2
5. tensorflow 2.4.1

please note: when I downgrade the numpy version to less than 1.20.0 I got another error which can't be solved without using numpy version 1.20.0 or above so downgrading numpy is not the right solution for my case

So pleas advise? knowing that downgrading python version will be so expensive as i need to create new anaconda environment and reinstall tensorflow object API's...

Comment: Does downgrading the tensorflow version to 2.2 solve the problem?

Comment: I solved the problem by downgrading the Tensorflow version from 2.4.1 to 2.4.0

Answer (score 0):

From comments

> Issue was resolved by downgrading the Tensorflow version from `2.4.1`
> to `2.4.0` (paraphrased from Husam Alhwadi).